# how to replace object in List<Map> at same index location in Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, maps

So lets say I have a list of objects like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [{'a': 'red', 'b': 'blue'}, {'a': 'yellow', 'b': 'orange'}, {'a': 'green', 'b': 'purple'}];
```

Assuming each a and b value is unique, how would I find the **object** where `a === yellow` and replace that object with a new object like `{'a': 'brown', 'b': 'white'}` **at the same index location** in the list of the original object?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention, I need to remove the object first to manipulate the data and then add it back at same location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var item = list.firstWhere((i) => i["a"] == 'yellow'); // getting the item
  var index = list.indexOf(item); // Item index
  list[index] = {'a': 'brown', 'b': 'white'}; // replace item at the index
```

Comment: Hi @Jhakiz, thank you for your answer.  I forgot to include that I need to remove first to change data and then add back at same location.  I was editing my question when you answered.  Could you please update your answer for that requirement?  Thanks

Comment: Which data want you add back? The new object or the existing (where a == 'yellow')??

Comment: a new object, but I may need to use data from the original object.  So I think I can use the first 2 lines of your code and then do a `list.removeAt(index)` followed by `list.insert(index, {'a': 'brown', 'b': 'white'})`.   Do you think that is ok or is there a better solution?

Comment: @steveny909 those two possibilities give the same result which you're looking for. `list[index] = {'a': 'brown', 'b': 'white'};` means remove the object on the index then add the new one.